# T-SQL Add Row With Zeros When Data Does Not Exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know this question has been answered a few times but I'm still having trouble adding an extra row while data doesn't exist until it does.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 

(
ID NVARCHAR(10)
,Number INT

)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',7)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',5)

 SELECT CASE WHEN ID = 'TG32' THEN 'Hats'
            WHEN ID =  'QD65' THEN 'Coats'
            WHEN ID =  'HT76' THEN 'Shoes'
            WHEN ID =   'WR52' THEN 'Shirts' END
            , Number


 FROM @Test
```

I'm trying to get an extra row in the results that says Shirts   0  while there is no data for ID WR52 until there is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 
(
ID NVARCHAR(10)
,Number INT

)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',7)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',5)

--
SELECT CASE WHEN ID = 'TG32' THEN 'Hats'
            WHEN ID =  'QD65' THEN 'Coats'
            WHEN ID =  'HT76' THEN 'Shoes'
            WHEN ID =   'WR52' THEN 'Shirts' END
            , Number
FROM @Test

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Shirts', 0
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @Test
        WHERE
            ID = 'WR52'
    )

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Hats', 0
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @Test
        WHERE
            ID = 'TG32'
    )


UNION ALL

SELECT 'Coats', 0
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @Test
        WHERE
            ID = 'QD65'
    )

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Shoes', 0
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @Test
        WHERE
            ID = 'HT76'
    )
```

Comment: Any idea how I would cover Hats, Coats and Shoes if data for these moved to another table , i.e no longer existed, I tried just extending the select list and adding ID IN ('Hats',Coats',Shoes',Shirts') but that doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that works was trying to think of a more compact way, but hey it works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a second table and use a left join to ensure that your categories always appear.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE ( ID NVARCHAR(10),Number INT )

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('TG32',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('QD65',3)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',7)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',1)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('HT76',5)

DECLARE @Categories TABLE ( ID NVARCHAR(10), Item NVARCHAR(10) )
INSERT INTO @Categories (ID, Item) VALUES
    ( 'TG32', 'Hats' ),
    ( 'QD65', 'Coats' ),
    ( 'HT76', 'Shoes' ),
    ( 'WR52', 'Shirts' )

SELECT C.Item, ISNULL(S.Number, 0) AS 'Number'
FROM @Categories C
LEFT JOIN @Test S ON C.ID = S.ID
```

This way you only have to add a new category in one place, and don't have to manually list which categories don't have any items.

Additionally, you perhaps want to get the totals for each item. You can do that like so:

```
SELECT C.Item, SUM(ISNULL(S.Number, 0)) AS 'Number'
FROM @Categories C
LEFT JOIN @Test S ON C.ID = S.ID
GROUP BY C.Item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ID = 'TG32' THEN 'Hats'
    WHEN ID = 'QD65' THEN 'Coats'
    WHEN ID = 'HT76' THEN 'Shoes'
    WHEN ID = 'WR52' THEN 'Shirts'
  END AS 'Item',
  Number
FROM @Test
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Shirts',
  0
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The  zero values need to appear so the client is aware that this product / stage is part of the process and they have yet to have accumulated any counts next to that product, it's just so they don't think we have missed anything off.

Comment: I will try to be mindful of this when asking questions in future!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case where you should be using a separate lookup table to map `Id` values to `Item` values. The same result can be had using a Common Table Expression (CTE) to create a lookup table with a really short lifespan:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Test as Table ( Id NVarChar(10), Number Int );
insert into @Test ( Id, Number ) values
  ('TG32',6), ('TG32',6), ('TG32',6), ('TG32',2), ('QD65',2),
  ('QD65',3), ('QD65',3), ('HT76',7), ('HT76',1), ('HT76',5);
select * from @Test;  

-- Using a CTE with a lookup table.
with ProductLookup as (
  select ProductCode, Item
    from ( values ( 'TG32', 'Hats' ), ( 'QD65', 'Coats' ), ( 'HT76', 'Shoes' ), ( 'WR2', 'Shirts' ) ) as
      Alpha( ProductCode, Item ) )
  select PL1.Item, T.Number
    from @Test as T inner join
      ProductLookup as PL1 on PL1.ProductCode = T.Id
  union all
  select Item, 0
    from ProductLookup as PL2
    where not exists ( select 42 from @Test where Id = PL2.ProductCode );
```

Note that this solution will generate a "zero" row for *any* missing product type, not just shirts.

Assumption: You are using SQL Server 2005 or later. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Comment: Sorry thought I had tagged t-sql and sqlserver/ I'm using sql server 2014